# Rest api url and data format issue

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

First of my Guest controller code for a rest api call is as followed:

```
protected function _retrieveCollection() 
{
    try 
    {
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParams('email');


         //check if email exists in db or not
         $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
         $customer->setWebsiteId(1);
         $customer->loadByEmail($email["email"]); //load customer by email i 

         if($customer->getId()>0){

             //send forgot password link
             $body = "Your forgot password link:- http://dev02-aws-sg01.zooyo.net/index.php/customer/account/changeforgotten/";
             $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
             $mail->setToEmail($email["email"]);
             $mail->setBody($body);
             $mail->setSubject('Forgot Password');
             $mail->setFromEmail('');
             $mail->setFromName("Admin");
             $mail->setType('html');// You can use 'html' or 'text'
             $mail->send();

             $array = array("status" => "200", "error" => "Email sent successfully.");
             return json_encode($array);
         }else{

             $array = array("status" => "500", "error" => "Email does not exists.");
             return json_encode($array);
         }


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $array = array("status" => "500", "error" => "Error in sending email");
        return json_encode($array);
    }   
}
```

The route which I hit is:

http://localhost:81/magento/api/rest/forgetpass

The output is:

[image]

As you can see in the image the json string is coming inside xml which is wrong, I want fully the output in json format. But let me be clear i dont want to override any file in magento for application format type.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 
`$email = $this->getRequest()->getParams('email');`

to `$email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');`

Also check that the email you are sending via **GET** or **POST** method is available in your database.

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Can you let me know how this will help me to get the output. Becuase I did this and no changes I can see.

Comment: You are using wrong syntax.. To get a single `param` you need to use ` $this->getRequest()->getParam('param');`. If this not help then try to check the param name may be there you are adding some space or there is some spelling mistake

Comment: http://dev02-aws-sg01.zooyo.net/api/rest/forgetpass/?email=aman@esoftech.org. Hit this url it will show success message showing inside xml.

Comment: Then the email you are sending via get this email is not in your database

Comment: I dont understand dear what you are trying to say becuase the questions which I asked and the replies which you are giving are totally different as per my question is concerned. :)

Comment: The error clearly mention you that the email is not exist. As Asish said try to check the email exist on your database.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to set the From or sender email and it will be

$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

```
$subject="Welcome ".$name;
$to="receiver_email"
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
->setToName($senderName)
->setToEmail($to)
->setBody($message)
->setSubject($subject)
->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
->setFromName($senderName)
->setType('html');
$mail->send();
```